# Boost-ASIO async_receive_from function overload issue (+ dynamic pointer)

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am trying to create a simple asynchronous receiver using the Boost library. I followed the examples as well as books, and this is what I was able to cook up so far:

```
class networkUDPClient {
public:
    utilityTripleBuffer * buffer;

    char testBuffer[20] = { 0 };

    const char * hostAddress;
    unsigned int port;

    boost::asio::io_service service;
    boost::asio::ip::udp::socket socket;
    boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint listenerEndpoint;
    boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint senderEndpoint;

    // Function Definitions
    void readCallback(const boost::system::error_code & err, std::size_t read_bytes) {

    }

    // Constructors
    networkUDPClient(const char * hostAddress, unsigned int port, unsigned int bufferSize) :
            socket(service),
            listenerEndpoint(boost::asio::ip::address_v4::from_string(hostAddress), port)
        {
            this->buffer = new utilityTripleBuffer(bufferSize, nullptr);

            this->hostAddress = hostAddress;
            this->port = port;

            socket.open(this->listenerEndpoint.protocol());
            socket.set_option(boost::asio::ip::udp::socket::reuse_address(true));
            socket.bind(this->listenerEndpoint);
            socket.async_receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(this->buffer->currentBufferAddr, this->buffer->bufferSize), 0, senderEndpoint, readCallback);
            service.run();
        };
    ~networkUDPClient()
        {
            service.stop();

            delete this->buffer;
        };
};
```

The problem is that **async_receive_from** function causes an error:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)      no instance of overloaded function "boost::asio::basic_datagram_socket::async_receive_from [with Protocol=boost::asio::ip::udp, DatagramSocketService=boost::asio::datagram_socket_service

I double checked the reference website as well as all my books, I believe I pass correct arguments and initialize them properly. What could be causing the issue?

BONUS QUESTION:

While I'm here, I would like to know whether using a dynamic pointer is acceptable in this case. I need to double buffer the data I receive, to give myself some time to process the previous frame. In this case **this->buffer->currentBufferAddr** will be changing after each time I receive data, pointing at different buffer every time.

Is this an acceptable way of doing things?

Comment: Tried to make the callback `static void readCallback` or use `bind` to bind `this`? The error message in the question is not complete

Comment: Pass `boost::bind(&networkUDPClient::readCallback, this,
    boost::asio::placeholders::error,
    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred` instead of just `readCallback`

Comment: The error message is exactly what Visual Studio provided me with. I would like to know why the function needs to be binded, while all the examples out there (including Torjo book) don't require that.

Comment: The non-static member functions have a _hidden_ `this` parameter but the handler prototype has no such parameter. So you can pass only normal functions, static member functions or lambdas. Otherwise you have to bind the first parameter to this and get a function taking only 2 parameters as reqired.

Comment: Thanks. Wish I could give you the kudos for the right answer. The book actually mentions why it doesn't work, but it's not very clear.

Comment: I have no experience with `boost::asio` and couldn't answer the bonus question, without further research :) I'm glad I could help

Answer (score 2):

First off, your parameters seem to be a little mixed up. [`async_receive_from`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_datagram_socket/async_receive_from/overload2.html) has the `flags` parameter as the **third parameter** while you have it as the **second**.

For the second part, you will have to either make the function static for all instances in order to pass it as handler, or bind it with `this` so the correct instance is called.

Bind it:

```
socket.async_receive_from
(
    boost::asio::buffer(buffer.data(), buffer.size()),
    senderEndpoint,
    0,
    std::bind(&readCallback, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2)
);
```

or if you make your `readCallback` static:

```
socket.async_receive_from
(
    boost::asio::buffer(buffer.data(), buffer.size()),
    senderEndpoint,
    0,
    readCallback
);
```

Comment: Thanks. Incorrectly placed flag argument definitely was one of the issues. Does the binding work for callback functions that do not take (const boost::system::error_code & err, std::size_t read_bytes) arguments? Lets say I want to pass a function pointer into the class, so that the callback executes whatever random function I desire. What do I need for that?

Comment: @AdmiralFishHead Always stick to the required parameters when binding, or you'll get most likely an error. _In theory_ you can pass any function signature to `std::bind`. Else I'm not quite sure what you mean, you might want to post another question.

Comment: Sure thing, once I stumble upon an error I cannot debug I will bring it up.

Comment: @AdmiralFishHead Please remember to accept an answer if it helped. Also on your old questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer